# Classification of subalgebras of a given dimension of $\textrm{End}(E)$ .

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, reference-request, vector-spaces

Let $k$ be a field, let $E$ be a $k$-vector space and let $\mathcal{A}$ be a subset of $\textrm{End}(E)$.

> **Proposition 1.** If $E$ is of dimension $2$, then $\mathcal{A}$ is a subalgebra of $\textrm{End}(E)$ of dimension $3$ if and only if there exists a line $\mathcal{D}$ of $E$ such that a $\mathcal{A}=\{u\in\textrm{End}(E)\textrm{ s.t. }u(\mathcal{D})\subseteq\mathcal{D}\}$.

*Proof.* The hard part is the direct implication. Here are the main steps:

- Construct a basis $(\textrm{id}_E,\varphi,\psi)$ of $\mathcal{A}$ such that $\varphi\circ\psi=0_{\textrm{End}(E)}$.
- Show that $\varphi$ and $\psi$ have a common eigenvector. Let $\mathcal{D}$ be the line spanned by this vector.
- Conclude using dimension, noticing that $\{u\in\textrm{End}(E)\textrm{ s.t. }u(\mathcal{D})\subseteq\mathcal{D}\}$ cannot be $\textrm{End}(E)$. $\Box$

I wonder whether or not the following generalization is true:

> **Proposition 2.** If $E$ is of dimension $n$, then $\mathcal{A}$ is a subalgebra of $\textrm{End}(E)$ of dimension $n^2-1$ if and only if there exists an hyperplane $\mathcal{H}$ of $E$ such that $\mathcal{A}=\{u\in\textrm{End}(E)\textrm{ s.t. }u(\mathcal{H})\subseteq\mathcal{H}\}$.

For proposition 2., I don't see what a suitable basis for $\mathcal{A}$ would be and consequently I don't really get how the hyperplane would come in place. In the proof of proposition 1., one uses the fact that $E$ is of dimension $2$ to show that $\varphi$ and $\psi$ have rank $1$ and hence have a common eigenvector, since $\textrm{im}(\psi)\subseteq\ker(\varphi)$.

> **Questions/Requests.** Do all subalgebras of $\textrm{End}(E)$ are achieved by a set of endomorphisms stabilizing a subvector space of $E$? If not, what are the subalgebras of $\textrm{End}(E)$ that can be represented in such a fashion? For the purposes of an exam, I am interested in a reference (preferably with an ISBN) where proposition 1. is entirely established.

Any enlightenment would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The endomorphisms of $E$ preserving a hyperplane have codimension $n-1$ and not codimension $1$, so in any case there should be a different dimension in Proposition 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andreas is right. More generally, let $F$ be a sub-vector space of $E$ of dimension $r$. Then the subalgebra $A=\{u\in L(E)|u(F)\subset F\}$ has dimension $n^2-rn+r^2$.

Proof. Let $B=B_r,B_{n-r}$ be a basis of $E$ st. $B_r$ is a basis of $F$. Then the associated matrix of $u\in A$ is in the form $\begin{pmatrix}U_r&c_{r,n-r}\\O_{n-r,r}&d_{n-r,n-r}\end{pmatrix}$. Consequently, $dim(A)=r^2+n(n-r)=n^2-rn+r^2$.

Your request. The answer is NO. Assume that $n=3$. According to the above proposition, such a proper sub-algebra, necessarily has dimension $7$. Thus, a counterexample is given by the sub-algebra of upper triangular matrices that has dimension $6$. Note that, when $n=3$, the dimensions of the proper sub-algebras are $1,2,3,4,5,6,7$ (not $8$).